# Rebase from another branch and then merge into master after merged the other branch

Tags: git, merge, rebase, branching-and-merging

I'm in this scenario:

- I have a master with a production version
- I worked on a new feature from master, without graphics (call it `feature`)
- In the same time, my team worked on a new branch from master for a new graphics features (call it `graphics`), where I worked too (keeping in standby the other branch)
- Now, the graphics is almost at the end and I come back to work into branch `feature`

The branch `graphics` will be merged into master after finished and reviewed, but now I want to integrate the `graphics` changes also into my branch `feature` that also will be merged with master after finished.

So we'll have to merge the `feature` into master, after `graphics` had been already merged.

What is the best way to do this? Could I rebase `feature` with `graphics` changes? Or merge `graphics` into `feature` (in this way will I have the merge `graphics` twice? )? Or must I cherry-pick all commits?

I hope is clear my scenario!

Comment: Perhaps something like: first, from `graphics`, `git rebase master` then from `master` `git merge graphics`. After, from `feature`, `git rebase master` and then, from `master`, `git merge feature` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, merge `graphics` into `master`. Then, rebase `feature` on top of `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge graphics
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

This way, you will acquire the `graphics` changes and still keep an uncluttered history in `feature`.

It is highly inadvisable to merge `graphics` into `feature` before merging it into `master` unless you have a particular reason for that.

But if you do have a particular reason, then just go ahead and do it...

```
git checkout feature
git merge graphics
```

Note that depending on circumstances you may want to do a `git rebase graphics` instead of `git merge graphics`. The end result (the content of your files on `feature`) will be exactly the same, but the history a.k.a. the commit tree will look different. The latter will avoid any kind of extra conflicts when you finally merge both branches into `master` and will look very clean; I would likely prefer that. But hard to tell without knowing what you want to achieve.

N.B. if you do a `git rebase`, and later commit more onto `graphics`, then you need to do the `git rebase` again before the final merge into `master` (I suggest doing that immediately after you merged `graphics` into `master`).

Comment: I want to integrate `graphics` change into `feature` while it should be finished yet, so I can't merge yet `graphics` into master. This is the reason of my crazy question :D I thought there should be a clean way to do this in git.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1, 
When the `graphics` is merged into the `master`;
In this case you can rebase your `feature` branch from the `master` as the `graphics` branch changes are there in `master`.

Scenario 2,
When the `graphics` branch isn't merged yet and you need the changes;
In this case there are two possibility,
i. Merge the `graphics` branch into your `feature` branch by just taking the `graphics` branch pull in the `feature` branch, say you in feature branch then `git pull origin graphics`.

ii. Do `rebase` your `feature` branch against the `graphics` branch, say you are feature branch the do `git rebase feature` and `git rebase --continue` unless all rebase conflicts and merge conflicts resolved.

The best is to rebase your branch with the `graphics` branch and then let the `graphics` branch be merged to `master` and then create a pull request agains the master. This would be great to do.